# Jumpcloud PHP LDAP connection

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, connection

I'm trying to setup a connection from my php code to jumpclouds ldap server. I have created a user on jumpcloud and the Ldap server. My php code:

```
<?php
    $ldap_dn = "uid=Johnjohn,ou=Users,o=62c54aa375bbe2273366ae3e,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com";
    $ldap_password = "Password1!";

    $ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap.jumpcloud.com");
    ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password))
        echo "Bind successful!";
    else
        echo "Invalid user/pass or other errors!";
```

I hit my else statement every time. My user on jumpcloud is active ofc.
So anything wrong with my code? or then I can share my settings from jumpcloud.

Edit: in my terminal when i ping ldap.jumpcloud i recived "request timed out" but when testing connection on https://www.filestash.app/ldap-test-tool.html?host=ldap.jumpcloud.com it says the jumpcloud server is online.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `@` error suppression?

Comment: Yes Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP-REST-API-LDAP-LOGIN\ldap\login.php on line 8
Invalid user/pass or other errors!

Comment: Can you try connecting using an alternative tool such as [ldapsearch](https://support.jumpcloud.com/support/s/article/using-ldapsearch-with-jumpcloud1), just to see if it is an account problem or a PHP one?

Comment: ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.jumpcloud.com:636 -x -b "ou=Users,o=62c54aa375bbe2273366ae3e,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com" -D "uid=Johnjohn,ou=Users,o=62c54aa375bbe2273366ae3e,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com" -W "(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)" what should I do with it past it in the terminal? and where should I put the user password?

Comment: That is a [Linux command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch), so you'll probably have to install it. If you can't install it, or are on a different platform, there's probably other tools, I'm just unfortunately not as familiar with those. That command's `-W` parameter is "prompt for password"